# How userId work while doing sftp using ssh keys?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to understand below scenario.

There is Server `A` and server `B`

server `A` pushes files to server `B` via ssh keys mechanism.

When server `B` get file pushed by server `A`, then what userID will be seen against that pushed file in server `B` ?

Is that possible where server `B` allows only specific userId to be used by server `A` to push files to it ? if yes, how that can be achieved ?

not aware of this logic in linux.

Please share.

Update: Server `B` has userID named as `serverB` and want server `A` also to be used the same userID `serverB`. Is it possible ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - the resulting owner and group depend on which user was used to copy the file.

Comment: @Panki, updated the question

Comment: What is a "userID" to you? The `uid` given by `id`? The username?

Comment: Lets say am server B and you are server A. I've userID userB and want you to use userB to push files to me.

Comment: In that case, a user named `userB` must exist on server `A` and you must know its password (or have a keyfile). This is not related to the actual `uid`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible where server B allows only specific userId to be used by server A to push files to it ? if yes, how that can be achieved ?

Whenever you set up SSH key authentication, you do it *for a particular user* at the destination server. It is the responsibility of the user at the source end to keep their private key secure, or to contact the administrator of the destination server to have th the public key removed from the appropriate `authorized_keys` file if the user has lost their key.

Note that neither the UID numbers nor usernames will have to match at both ends of the connection: the SSH client might theoretically be on an embedded system which might not even have a concept of user accounts at all.

You can use the same keypair for multiple connections, or have a separate keypair for each connection, or any combination in between. It would be technically possible to add the same public key to all user accounts on server B and so allow the user holding the corresponding private key to log in as any user on server B; but that would usually be a very silly thing to do.

(Every time something unfortunate would happen on server B, all the other users could say "It was not me. It must have been the holder of the Master Key logging in using my account." And the blame would be shifted.)

By default, whoever holds the private key of a SSH key pair will be able to log in to an account on a server that has the public part of the same key pair added to the user account's `authorized_keys` file, *no matter where the connection comes from or who the key holder claims to be at the other end of the connection*.

It is possible to set up additional constraints within the `authorized_keys` file: you can restrict the key authentication to only work if the connection is coming from a particular IP address or hostname, or a IP- or hostname-based wildcard pattern. For more details, see the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` paragraph in `man sshd` on your system: the exact options available may vary in different `sshd` versions.

There is usually no point in restricting by the client-side username, as the server has generally no better way to find that out than by asking the SSH client... and the client might be hacked and tell lies. Unless the user has allowed their private key to get into wrong hands, the successful key-based authentication is already a pretty strong proof that the user is authorized to use that specific account on the destination server.

So, in your case, if server `serverA` pushes files to server `serverB` with `scp /some/files B:/some/directory`, and the command is executed as user `userA`, then the `scp` command will attempt to transfer the files by logging in as `userA` to server `serverB` by default.

The default can be changed by specifying the destination username in the command: `scp /some/files userB@serverB:/some/directory` will cause the files to be transferred by logging in as `userB` to `serverB`.

The destination username can also be specified in the SSH client configuration file: if `userA` has a configuration like this in their `~/.ssh/config` file on `serverA`, then `scp /some/files serverB:/some/directory` will also transfer the files by logging in to `serverB` as `userB` when `userA` runs the command on `serverA`.

```
Host serverB
    User userB
```